# Python, beautiful soup, get all class name

Tags: python, html, class, beautifulsoup

given an html code lets say:

```html
 <div class="class1">
    <span class="class2">some text</span>
    <span class="class3">some text</span>
    <span class="class4">some text</span>
    </div>
```

How can I retrieve all the class names? ie: ['class1','class2','class3','class4']

I tried:

```
soup.find_all(class_=True)
```

But it retrieves the whole tag and i then need to do some regex on the string

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can [treat each `Tag` instance found as a *dictionary*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) when it comes to retrieving attributes. Note that `class` attribute value would be a *list* since `class` is a special ["multi-valued" attribute](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#multi-valued-attributes):

```py
classes = []
for element in soup.find_all(class_=True):
    classes.extend(element["class"])
```

Or:

```py
classes = [value
           for element in soup.find_all(class_=True)
           for value in element["class"]]
```

**Demo:**

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div class="class1">
<span class="class2">some text</span>
<span class="class3">some text</span>
<span class="class4">some text</span>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

classes = [value
           for element in soup.find_all(class_=True)
           for value in element["class"]]

print(classes)

# Returns
# ['class1', 'class2', 'class3', 'class4']
```

Comment: Demo as very insightful, helped me do what I needed.