# Extract value of 'class' under a div tag using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

using Python 3.6.5.

```
<div class="abcabcd13"></div>  
<div class="abcabcd74"></div>  
<div class="abcabcd123"></div>
```

The above is the html code I've managed to extract using BeautifulSoup 4, and I've managed to assign the list of them to a variable with:
    `x = soup.select('div[class*=abcab]'),`which creates a list of elements like`<div class="abcabcd13"></div>`. How do I extract just the class value? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, beautiful soup, get all class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43751699/python-beautiful-soup-get-all-class-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using selectors to get the required output:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = """\
<div class="abcabcd13"></div>  
<div class="abcabcd74"></div>  
<div class="abcabcd123"></div>  
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
classlist = [' '.join(item.get('class')) for item in soup.select("[class^='abcabcd']")]
print(classlist)
```

Output:

```
['abcabcd13', 'abcabcd74', 'abcabcd123']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I just did it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = """<div class="abcabcd13"></div>  
          <div class="abcabcd74"></div>  
          <div class="abcabcd123"></div>  """
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
divs = soup.findAll("div")
classes = []
for y in divs:
    classes.append(y["class"])
print(classes)
```

which printed the three  classes.

Comment: Excellent! The only issue I see is that it prints: [['abcabcd13'], ['abcabcd74'], ['abcabcd123']] instead of ['abcabcd13','abcabcd74','abcabcd123']. How do you suggest we should go about removing the extra "[" and "]"?